# Specify jdk per maven sub-module - and fail build if wrong is used

Tags: maven, java

Using the maven-compiler-plugin its possible to specify the supported jdk for a project:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>

                <fork>true</fork>
                <!-- <executable>path-to-javac</executable> -->
                <compilerVersion>1.5</compilerVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But is it possible to fail the build if another version of a JDK is used?

I have some code that use **javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters** which is not part of 1.5 but since I build with a JDK6 that contains this package the build succeeds.

Inside eclipse I get warnings but it could be nice to make the build fail without explicitly modifying the JDK used when building the project.

I have tried this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce-versions</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <requireJavaVersion>
              <version>1.5</version>
            </requireJavaVersion>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

but it does nothing. I have also tried to put in the plugin management:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
              <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                  <goal>enforce</goal>
                </goals>
              </pluginExecutionFilter>
              <action>
                <ignore></ignore>
              </action>
            </pluginExecution>
          </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

but has no effect either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `maven-enforcer-plugin` will fail for you if you change the `<version/>` tag.

The [Maven Version Range Specification](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html) will tell you how to specify version ranges.

```
<version>1.5</version>
```

will mean `version >= 1.5`

You should declare

```
<version>[1.5]</version>
```

which will mean `version == 1.5` and the enforcer will fail the build if you use a JDK with version 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>
```